# How to organize four pictures? (beside and among each other combinded)

Tags: graphics, subfloats, minipage

I am trying to organize 4 pictures in the following way:

[image]

I know how to organize two pictures beside each other with a minipage or how to bring two pictures among each other with subfigures but I don't know how to do this combined.

At the moment I don't have a working example for this.

Could someone be so kind and show me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you load the `subfigure` package, use a `minipage` environment to place the first three subfigures, and employ a plain `subfigure` environment for the fourth subfigure. (Obviously, the relative widths of `0.65\textwidth` and `0.3\textwidth`, as well as the `height` values of 1.5cm and 3.85cm are just for the sake of illustration. Your real figures probably have different dimensions anyway.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\renewcommand\figurename{Illustration}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=true}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.5cm]{graph_a}
\caption{Picture 1}
\end{subfigure}  
% the following line must be blank, to create a line break:

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.5cm]{graph_b}
\caption{Picture 2}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.5cm]{graph_c}
\caption{Picture 3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.85cm]{graph_d}
\caption{Picture 4}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{My pictures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Am I allowed to use the code for my thesis?

Comment: @ce_guy - Of course you're allowed. (All code on this site is licensed under the Creative Commons license.)

Comment: How do the different subfigure environments "know" from each other so that the labeling a, b,... still works?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - A `subfigure` environment is a (thinly-disguised) `minipage` environment that "knows" what to do with a `\caption` statement, *viz.*, to increment a counter called (you guessed it) `subfigure` and to typeset the caption. The layout of `subfigure` environments obeys the rules that apply to the layout of `minipage` environments. The overall layout shown above has one `minipage` -- containing 3 interior `subfigure` environments -- on the left, and another "disguised" `minipage` (the fourth `subfigure`) on the right.